# Change value of webkit filter every seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to change the webkit filter value of element every seconds with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");

    function setOpacity() {
        var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var str = regExp.exec($(".content").css("-webkit-filter"));
        var currentValue = str[0].substring(1).slice(0, -1);
        console.log(currentValue);

        $(".content").css("-webkit-filter", "opacity(" + parseFloat(currentValue) + 0.01 + " %) grayscale(70%);");
    }
    var t = setInterval(setOpacity, 1000);
});
```

But the code doesn't work. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: maybe you wanted to use *0.01 instead of + ?

Comment: What's the point of this code at all ? Do you want to animate the opacity value ? You could make this using CSS animation instead

Comment: @pomeh Yes it is the case. How did i do with css animation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 keyframe animations](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) to accomplish that. My example is to fade from 0 to 1 (or 0% to 100%, that is) in one second:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(70%);
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s 0s 1 ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The animation shorthand is written in the following order: animation name, duration, delay, iteration, timing-function. The order does not matter except for duration, delay and iteration.

See JSfiddle for proof-of-concept example: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/A85vZ/. You might want to run the fiddle after loading it, because you'll probably miss the animation :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSS-transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) for that.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
    opacity: 0; 
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 2s; /* Short syntax: " transition: opacity 2s;" */
}

.show{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.content').addClass('show');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/dLHLx/)